# $P(X+Y=n)=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}P(X=m)P(Y=n-m)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent, integer-valued r.v.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent, integer-valued random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. Prove that

$$P(X+Y=n)=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}P(X=m)P(Y=n-m)$$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I really have no idea how to start this, any hints or points in the right direction would be much appreciated. This is exercise 2.1.13 in https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTEv5a.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How can $X + Y = 3$ happen? One way is $\{X=3, Y=0\}$. Another way is $\{X=2, Y=1\}$. Yet another is $\{X=-10, Y=13\}$. If you consider all possible ways, can you give an expression for $P(X+Y=3)$ in terms of an infinite sum?

> $$P(X+Y = 3) = \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} P(X=m, Y=3-m)$$

Then recall that independence of $X$ and $Y$ implies $P(X=x, Y=y) = P(X=x) P(Y=y)$.

Comment: Why can we just say that $P(X+Y=3)=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}P(X=m,Y=3-m)$? Intuitively it makes sense, but why is it indeed the case?

Comment: Think about it in terms of conditional probability. Condition on the event that $X =m$, and then sum over all these events using the law of total probability to get the un-conditional probability.

Comment: What about $\{X=n,Y=n-m\}$ is a family of disjoint sets and so when we take the probability of their union, we can just take the sum of the probabilities since $P$ is a measure. Then apply independence?

Comment: @Gengar Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you so much @angryavian!